# Why is the US listed as a "flawed democracy" in the Democracy Index?

Tags: united-states, democracy, government

I was reading Wikipedia's [Democracy Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) and it shows the United States as a "Flawed Democracy". Reading in more detail, the article points out that the US has low scores in "Functioning of Government" (6.43) and also in "Political Culture" (6.25), but I don't understand those terms.

Why is the US listed as a "flawed democracy" in the [Democracy Index](https://www.eiu.com/n/campaigns/democracy-index-2021/)? How should I interpret that?

I guess my real concern is if there is a problem, then I would like to understand it first, and then somehow vote to improve it.

Comment: Related question: [Why does the US have such a low score for "Political participation" factor in the Democracy index?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/34566)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39963/why-is-the-us-ranked-as-45-in-press-freedom-ratings-despite-its-extremely-perm

Comment: The answers here so far do not consider voter suppression and gerrymandering.  Does the Democracy Index consider those?

Answer (score 87):

The [Economist Intelligence Unit](https://www.eiu.com/n/) (a subsidiary of the Economist group best known for [its publication](https://www.economist.com/)) publishes its Democracy Index every year.  It seems that the latest, 2021, requires registration, but [last years is freely available](https://pages.eiu.com/rs/753-RIQ-438/images/democracy-index-2020.pdf).  It answers your question fairly comprehensively, starting on page 42.  In summary:

- The US also remains in the “flawed democracy” category, having fallen out of the “full democracy” division in 2016
- Principally blamed on "further erosion of public trust in the country’s institutions — a development that preceded the election of Donald Trump as president that year"
- Other reasons given are:

  - extremely low levels of trust in institutions and political parties
  - deep dysfunction in the functioning of government
  - increasing threats to freedom of expression
  - a degree of societal polarisation that makes consensus on any issue almost impossible to achieve
  - differences of opinion in the US have hardened into political sectarianism and institutional gridlock
  - public trust in the democratic process was dealt a further blow in 2020 by the refusal of the outgoing president to accept the election result
  - The consequence of the long-running culture wars in the US and the heightened political polarisation of recent years is that social cohesion has collapsed and consensus has evaporated on fundamental issues, such as election outcomes, public health practices and even the date of the
    country’s founding
  - The cleavage in US politics has long been amplified by the mainstream media, including the main network TV channels which make no pretence of impartiality, but in 2020 social media companies intervened in a way that is likely to reinforce the divisions in American society
  - Personal freedoms also declined in 2020

Comment: `Personal freedoms also declined in 2020` As I noted in my own answer, there's no explanation here. What personal freedoms declined? Australia and the UK ("full democracies") both had hard Covid lockdowns for months on end. The US had some... but restrictions lifted soon after, depending on where you lived. Does that factor into this? They never explain any of that.

Comment: @Machavity They give some explanation beyond Covid lockdowns: it also reflects a rise of militarised tactics by the authorities to suppress non-violent demonstrations. One example was the aggressive clearing of Lafayette Square near the White House in June 2020, when the National Guard used chemical agents and other riot-control techniques to disperse a crowd before the announced curfew. The demonstrators were peacefully protesting against police brutality and the killing of George Floyd, an unarmed black man.

Comment: @Machavity: "However, in line with
global trends, both countries [US & Canada] did worse in the “citizens control” and “personal freedom” indicators,
owing in part to the introduction of coronavirus-related restrictions."

Comment: How can things that happened in 2020 be responsible for the EIU dropping the ranking in 2016?

Comment: Hm... Most of the EIU reasoning revolves around 'polarisation'. But this is societal change, not (at least directly) the result of democracy as a system of governance. Now it turns out that democracy itself can't cope well with hard polarisation. So what is actually flawed here? Democracy as such, the US just being in an advanced stage of the 'polarisation disease'? Or the US, for trying to use tools (i.e. democracy) which are unable to solve its problems?

Comment: @Zeus Many would argue that the two party system strongly contributes to and supports any polarization that occurs.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica This may be a flaw in the bullet point structure I have gone with.  The cause of the drop in 2016 was "further erosion of public trust in the country’s institutions", the other points are related to the current score.

Comment: @Zeus I do not think this point is closely examined in the document.  I would posit that it is the people who are involved in the democracy that are flawed, in that they are taking stances and using language that is designed to increase polarisation as a political tool.  The use of "wedge issues" would seem an example of such behaviour.

Comment: If it was republished now I'm pretty sure it would also list "attempts by legislative bodies to take control of elections away from independent bodies" would be added.

Comment: @David, OK, then it follows that the two-party version of democracy is flawed? (Presumably, those of them that are still 'full democracies' (UK, NZ, Australia) haven't (yet?) fallen to this disease). But there are counter-examples of pluralist (multi-party) 'flawed democracies' where this pluralism is ostensibly a hindrance to a functioning government (say, Israel recently). So again, is the system inherently flawed? And those examples that are not (yet) just haven't been tested properly? (A good system must allow for unreliable/flawed components (people in this case)...)

Comment: @Zeus I think you have to consider these points as a whole. No single issue creats a flawed democracy by itself, but the combination of many of them does. The US has had a 2-party system for a very long time, but it didn't become dysfunctional until recently.

Comment: @Zeus The UK is far less of a two-party system than the US is. There are ten different parties represented in the House of Commons, plus nine independent MPs (though admittedly they were elected as party members and then expelled for misbehaviour of some kind), plus a substantial number of crossbenchers and others with no party affiliation in the House of Lords. And a party other than one of the two main ones was in the national government from 2010 to 2015, while the Scottish Parliament and Northern Ireland Assembly are both controlled by parties other than the big two.

Comment: @User65535 this just shows the bias of the authors and why this entire index is untrustworthy. In the same year as the Lafayette square protest (which was not peaceful btw there were some demonstrators who were throwing things including bricks at the cops) there were completely peaceful lockdown protests that were brutally broken up in places like Germany and Australia which was all caught on video. Those countries also have severe speech restrictions on certain topics yet they rank much higher on civil liberties. The authors implicitly consider those liberty infringements good and ignorable.

Comment: @Eugene This is not a subject that can be defined objectively, so clearly there will be some judgement calls. As I mentioned above, you have to look at all the factors, not single out specific issues or events.

Answer (score 44):

> the US has low scores in "Functioning of Government" (6.43) and also in "Political Culture" (6.25), but I don't understand those terms.

**Lack of Compromise Politics.**

This is what I think the "political culture" index reflects.

Normal politics has always depended on trading off what one side wants againsts what others want.  It absolutely depends on compromise to work.  Without compromise you have political deadlocks and chaos.

In the US it seems that far too many issues, big and small, are now pursued along bitter hard line approaches.  Compromises are begrudging at best and absent at worst.

In practical politics we *need* politicians to be pragmatic about getting things done.  The fact that a solution is not the ideal one you want should not be bar to making an agreement.  One piece of a pie is better than no pie at all.

Politicians in the US (although not only the US) are increasingly adopting hard line stances and engaging in political retoric which attract and entrenches extreme positions.  In a healthy political culture a politician always leaves themselves room for compromise because they know eventually that achieving any practical goal will need compromise.  In the US politicians are now adopting positions where they have no wiggle room.

Politicians are, I think, afraid to express the view that, yes, compromise is a necessary and a good thing.

This is fear is amplified by a media which feeds off the polarization of every political issue.  Politicians who fail to meet the unreasonable expectation of not giving an inch get lacerated by the media.

**Functioning of Government.**

The US has had trouble even agreeing a budget.  When you cannot pay your own civil servants, not for lack of funds, but because you cannot agree to write the check, it's bad.  That's a pretty awful state of play for a nation that identifies itself as a Capitalist state.  That and the invasion of the seat of US government by a mob makes it clear the US is barely hanging on to a healthy political culture, if it is still hanging on at all.

A significant issue with a functioning government is that you ideally want one that works even when the politicians don't.  That what a Civil Service is for.  They keep the wheels in motion.  A significant issue in the US is that there's a lot of political levers inside what should be the Civil Service.  Where most countries have permanently employed officials, you have people who are elected or emplaced by political decisions.  This makes the apparatus of government vulnerable to political exploitation in more direct way than the better democracies do.

You cannot have a functioning government when you politically interfere with it all the time.  You have to let the train run on the tracks.  You can't keep applying brake and accelerator together all the time.  You cannot exclusively appoint people based on their political alignment and expect that to work because it means that every time the boss changes so does everyone else.  It would be like a sports team getting a new coach and deciding to fire all the players and the coaching staff as well.  You need some steady hands at the wheel.

The weakest link is, IMO, the Supreme Court.  This was always politicized and where it should be providing a stabilizing limit to prevent everything that has been done from being undone, the political nature of the appointment process means that when you need stability at the wheel, you've got people who are happy instead to spin the wheel madly around in the opposite direction.

That's called reckless driving where I come from.  It's hard to imagine the European Court of Human Rights doing a U-turn like that.

The US cannot rely on the courts, it's civil service or it's politicians to reach reasonable solutions to problems by compromising.

That's a barely functioning government.

Comment: But why it's a barely functioning government? If the Supreme Court is the biggest problem, how can other countries maintain a more balanced Supreme Court? Or why is it so difficult to agree a budget? With only two parties, there should always be one with a majority. Or is the inbuilt checks and balances causing too much friction. Do other countries have less checks and balances maybe? How get budgets agreed upon for example in Sweden or New Zealand?

Comment: Court appointments are not so politically motivated in other countries.  Indeed the laywers themselves view law as necessarily independent of politics.  It's clear that to get on SCOTUS you *must* be politically aligned with the prevailing powers of the day.  You can't agree a budget because no one will sit down quietly and make political compromises.  In the US *everything* has become a political issue, even paying for things you have to pay for and still want done, like all those things the civil service is needed for.  It's not about checks and balances, it's refusal to compromise.

Comment: Congress is primarily paralyzed because of filibuster in the Senate. If that rule was removed, Congress would pass tons of laws as long as both chambers are controlled by the same party (As is the case right now).

Comment: @JonathanReez The filibuster was there a long time and did not prevent normal politics been done.  It's become a habit for US politicians to increasingly act to be extremist about policies without making any serious attempt at finding a compromise or middle ground, or in some cases by refusing to even consider such a thing.  The problem is the support for extremist positions - the "if I can't have it my way, no one can have anything" attitude.  People need to see it for what it is - juvenile.  Removing filibusters won't prevent this kind of obstruction IMO.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine there's literally no other country with filibuster, except for South Korea: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33426/do-any-legislative-branches-besides-the-us-have-a-tradition-of-voluntarily-requi. And European countries have tons of problems too, Belgium being a prime example.

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm not pro filibusters and they're replaced by other legal tactics.  European countries have problems in far less extreme ways.  I don''t the EU's governmental issues as anything like as bad as the US.  There's a compromise mentality and a well defined processes and strong belief in doing normal poliitics to hammer out deals.  This is not working in the US at Federal or State level.  In the US I think they've simply lost sight of the need to compromise.  EU states do compromise and it works.  It used to for US states, the US needs that back.

Comment: "Politicians are, I think, afraid to express the view that, yes, compromise is a necessary and a good thing." - What are you talking about? Biden explicitly ran on "more bipartisanship" as a central plank of his campaign. The fact that bipartisanship subsequently failed to materialize is indeed a problem, but it does not indicate a lack of *desire* for bipartisanship among the electorate.

Comment: "It's not about checks and balances, it's refusal to compromise." That's what I don't understand. With only two parties always one must have a majority, so there is no need for compromise. In other countries with say 5 different parties I understand that need and how a refusal could be dangerous, but in the US? Under Trump Republicans controlled Congress and presidency and still couldn't for example build a wall towards Mexico and I also don't see how making more compromises could have built more wall (just for an example).

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Thank you for the explanation of those two terms. I coulnd't understand them in the first place and I was really confused. Thank you again.

Comment: Just a nitpick: The word political has [horribly conflicting definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/political). By definition 1, the court is by definition political. So, I would use another word just for the sake of disambiguation. I believe in US politics, the fundamental problem which polarizes opinion about SCOTUS is that we can't even agree what the function of the court is. Same goes for other government institutions.

Comment: @Trilarion, also with a bicameral legislature you might need to have a majority in _both_ chambers, not just one, so it's not true that there'd always be a usable majority. That, plus needing to also have the president in the same league...

Comment: @ilkkachu "with a bicameral legislature you might need to have a majority in both chambers, not just one, so it's not true that there'd always be a usable majority." That's what I meant with checks and balances, and I can see how this leads to gridlock, but this answer rather states that this is not the problem.

Comment: "Political deadlocks and chaos" is actually "political deadlocks and stability". Chaos is when politicians agree and begin changing laws. This creates chaos as businesses and the public must recalibrate to a changing set of rules and regulations (which may, shortly thereafter, change again). Political deadlock is peace and stability. Literal peace if they can't even agree on which wars to fund.

Comment: @JamieB "Chaos is when politicians agree and begin changing laws." I thought the appropriate term is progress or democracy. Some kind of continuity might be nice but the world is changing all the time and laws need to adapt. A democracy should have a prerogative to actually do something. And wars happen nevertheless.

Comment: @Kevin  Every single time (except maybe Trump) I have seen a politician's acceptance speech, anywhere in the world, they always mention how they look forward to "working WITH their opposition" etc., but that is just fluff, what they really mean is that if the opposition get in their way, they will cast all blame in that direction.

Comment: @Trilarion - Every politician and political party throughout history thought their changes were the progressive ones leading their people to a brighter future. I think we can only call it "progress" in retrospect, after seeing how it went. In immediate terms, I think we can only call it "change" (though I still prefer "chaos").

Comment: @JamieB There is nothing special about the status quo, except maybe that one could argue that since we all still exist it cannot be a total failure, but that is probably a very low bar. On the other hand the World is constantly changing so a reaction to that might be appropriate. Even if I knew nothing I would probably prefer change or in your words chaos over order.

Comment: @JamieB The problem here is that both chaos, progress, order/stability have implicit connotations of desirability or lack thereof. Neither term is neutral and therefore neither term is suitable if your stance is that things can only be judged in retrospect. The only neutral terms and I can think of is are is "change" and "no change", which no one uses because it doesn't promote whatever point they are trying to get across.

Comment: @JamieB chaos: the status quo is suddenly imperilled when *nothing* is funded, because no budget can pass

Comment: @user34211 "I believe in US politics, the fundamental problem which polarizes opinion about SCOTUS is that we can't even agree what the function of the court is. Same goes for other government institutions."

I disagree. The function of the court and other institutions is explicitly laid out in the constitution. The court is to enforce the law, not to take liberties in creating law. That's the job of the congress. But politicians can't help themselves stealing power where the opportunity arises.

Comment: @Caleth The U.S. federal government is borrowing nearly $800 billion just between now and the end of the 2023, and nearly $900 billion between Jan and March 2024. The interest payment alone on the federal debt is $660B this year and will soon be a trillion. The borrowing is happening because it isn't even possible, if the federal government took every penny of everybody's income, to fund the budget. It is grotesquely, comically, tragically out of control. The day's coming where the congress prints treasure bonds, and nobody will be standing in line to buy them, including the Federal Reserve.

Comment: Does everyone know where money comes from? All of the money in the economy comes from bank loans. Home loans, car loans, all the loans. The Federal Reserve is a group of banks, not a government agency. When the federal government "prints money", they print treasury bonds, which the Federal Reserve buys. By law (the bonds were printed via a bill in congress) the bonds are bought back on a specific date at a specific interest rate. That's just a fancy name for a loan. The Federal Reserve bank (and any other countries/entities who buy the bonds) are just making a loan to the federal government.

Comment: When repayment starts looking like a bad bet, even the Federal Reserve doesn't have to buy the bonds. The jacked fed interest rate, combined with the fact that $33 Trillion of debt is in the process of getting refinanced at the new higher rate, means the interest payment will balloon into the trillions. The federal government collected $5 Trillion in taxes in 2022. That's it. We could actually end up in a situation where the interest payment on the debt alone consumes all tax revenue. It's time to stop arguing about spending more and start figuring out how NOT to spend.

Answer (score 18):

As noted [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/34567/12027), some of the index is very arbitrary.

> The USA scores well for literacy and membership of political parties, but is still at 19% for women in the House, and doesn't score full points on indices such as percentage interest in news media and turn-out at elections.

The number system for the ranks is also very arbitrary. The range for "flawed democracy" is 6.00 to 7.99. The United States ranks as a 7.85. As recently as 2015, the US was in the "full democracy" category. There's also not much discussion of how the rankings were measured specifically for the US. For contrast, Canada (a solid "full democracy" at 8.87), saw it's Prime Minister [invoke the Emergencies Act](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-60381096) against political protesters

> But while Mr Trudeau's government may soon be granted an almost carte blanche to respond to the protests, there is no indication the prime minister will also seek military intervention.
>
> While Mr Trudeau has said that "everything is on the table", he has maintained that military involvement would be a last resort.
>
> "We are a long way from having to call in the military," he said on Friday.

That military options were even on the table against political protesters doesn't seem very much like a "full democracy". Even [having your bank account suspended by the government](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/emergencies-act-banks-ottawa-protests-1.6353968) is pretty extreme.

Ultimately, all democracies are flawed, in that they are run by flawed humans, for flawed humans. The problem with the category of "flawed democracy" here is that it's a purely arbitrary category for poorly defined numbers. The United States seems no more or less flawed than the countries in the "full democracy" category, and the numbers from the report itself back that up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137803/discussion-on-answer-by-machavity-why-is-the-us-listed-as-a-flawed-democracy-i).

Comment: The protesters were politically *motivated*, but they weren't just marching with signs.  They had trucks blocking major streets and bridges, including a border crossing 24/7.  (And the police were not being effective at dealing with those traffic violations.) So it's certainly not great, but for readers not familiar with the situation, your answer reads like Trudeau making an arbitrary crackdown on anti-vax opponents (and whatever else the truckers represented). There was a real urgent problem that needed solving somehow, with businesses being unable to open, not normal for Canadian protests.